# Public key encryption on TPM2 using TSS.NET

Tags: .net, public-key-encryption, tpm

Is it possible to implement public key encryption in a .Net application using a TPM2 and the [TSS.NET library](https://github.com/microsoft/TSS.MSR/tree/master/TSS.NET) by microsoft?
To be more specific, the part that should be done in the TPM is the decryption using the private key and therefore the public key should be able to be exported to other machines.
Additionally the keys should be stored in the TPM2 module.

I studied/worked through the examples by Microsoft and read the [documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/TSS.MSR/blob/master/Using%20the%20TSS.Net%20Library.docx), but I did not find information on that topic or or I missed it somehow.

To store data in the TPM2, I found nv memory, but as far as I understand, this is used to store data from outside the TPM2 module in it, but I don't know if/how it is possible to store some kind of keys from inside the TPM2 module in its nv memory to be used at next boot again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to exist sample code for C# (yet) however there is [some sample C++ code](https://github.com/microsoft/TSS.MSR/blob/a1458bf14bc1adadc08090f8801cf7cd36314fef/TSS.CPP/Samples/Samples.cpp#L2423) that demonstrates what you want:

```
void Samples::RsaEncryptDecrypt()
{
    Announce("RsaEncryptDecrypt");

    // This sample demostrates the use of the TPM for RSA operations.

    // We will make a key in the "null hierarchy".
    TPMT_PUBLIC primTempl(TPM_ALG_ID::SHA1,
                          TPMA_OBJECT::decrypt | TPMA_OBJECT::userWithAuth | TPMA_OBJECT::sensitiveDataOrigin,
                          null,  // No policy
                          TPMS_RSA_PARMS(null, TPMS_SCHEME_OAEP(TPM_ALG_ID::SHA1), 2048, 65537),
                          TPM2B_PUBLIC_KEY_RSA());

    // Create the key
    auto storagePrimary = tpm.CreatePrimary(TPM_RH_NULL, null, primTempl, null, null);

    TPM_HANDLE& keyHandle = storagePrimary.handle;

    ByteVec dataToEncrypt = TPM_HASH::FromHashOfString(TPM_ALG_ID::SHA1, "secret");
    cout << "Data to encrypt: " << dataToEncrypt << endl;

    auto enc = tpm.RSA_Encrypt(keyHandle, dataToEncrypt, TPMS_NULL_ASYM_SCHEME(), null);
    cout << "RSA-encrypted data: " << enc << endl;

    auto dec = tpm.RSA_Decrypt(keyHandle, enc, TPMS_NULL_ASYM_SCHEME(), null);
    cout << "decrypted data: " << dec << endl;
    if (dec == dataToEncrypt)
        cout << "Decryption worked" << endl;
    _ASSERT(dataToEncrypt == dec);

    // Now encrypt using TSS.C++ library functions
    ByteVec mySecret = tpm._GetRandLocal(20);
    enc = storagePrimary.outPublic.Encrypt(mySecret, null);
    dec = tpm.RSA_Decrypt(keyHandle, enc, TPMS_NULL_ASYM_SCHEME(), null);
    cout << "My           secret: " << mySecret << endl;
    cout << "My decrypted secret: " << dec << endl;
    _ASSERT(mySecret == dec);

    // Now with padding
    ByteVec pad { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0 };
    enc = storagePrimary.outPublic.Encrypt(mySecret, pad);
    dec = tpm.RSA_Decrypt(keyHandle, enc, TPMS_NULL_ASYM_SCHEME(), pad);
    cout << "My           secret: " << mySecret << endl;
    cout << "My decrypted secret: " << dec << endl;
    _ASSERT(mySecret == dec);

    tpm.FlushContext(keyHandle);
} // RsaEncryptDecrypt()
```

Of course instead of creating a new primary key you would probably want to use the SRK or a child key.

Comment: Thank You, this seems to be what I want, but I get an exception, although I adapted the the code to c#/.Net and used the right constants and constructors instead of the preprocessor macros (like TpmRh.Null instead of TPM_RH_NULL).


`The Exception is Tpm2Lib.TpmException: Error {Symmetric} was returned for command CreatePrimary.
Details:
[Code=TpmRc.Symmetric],[RawCode=0x2D6,726]
[ErrorEntity=Parameter], [ParmNum=2]
[ParmName=inPublic]`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.


I uploaded it to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/FASwXXHc)


This is my current code. It is basically just the C++ code "translated" to C# and I used the Authorization-Sample as "frame" for the code.
The parameters, that are commented out are the ones, I already tried instead of the current parameters in the same line.
I tried what seemed logical to me.
I think I use some wrong parameters, but I was not able to figure out, what I have to change.